# Import client certificate domain-wide into Google Chrome (Google Apps for Work)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, ssl-certificate

We have rolled out a lot of chromebooks and for an internal application we need to import a client certificate into Google Chrome. We don't want to let our users import the certificate. After some research we think the best approach is to create a Google Chrome extension, see for details:
http://www.chromium.org/administrators/certificate-management-extension-api-on-chrome-os

The chrome.enterprise.platformKeys is only available for pre-installed extensions within a Google Apps for Work domain which makes development difficult, because you can't easy debug (publishing the extension takes 1 hour). We do have the client certificate locally. How can we use the api to import this certificate (file)? (no CA server)

Comment: I never worked with pre-installed extensions; if you have Developer Mode enabled, can you open the extension for debugging with Dev Tools?

Comment: Yes but I can't make any chrome.enterprise.platformKeys API calls when I add an unpacked extension this message appear `There were warnings when trying to install this extension:
'enterprise.platformKeys' is not allowed for specified install location` this message disappear when I pre-install the extension

Comment: Not _unpacked_. Can you debug a running, packed extension? Then you can execute arbitrary code in the console of the background page. You can make a dummy extension for debugging purposes.

Comment: ah sorry for the misunderstanding. Yes I can. In the console it doesn't recognize `chrome.enterprise` which returns `Undefined`.

Comment: Oh well, then this is protected from such fiddling.